# Matter.js Collision Filter Options Disappear and Reappear?

Tags: javascript, undefined, simulation, physics, matter.js

I was building a simple simulation,
I needed more than the 32 categories,
So I implemented the suggested solution to define a `Detector.canCollide` function to allow me to do so.

```
Detector.canCollide = function (filterA, filterB) {
    console.log(filterB)
    return (filterB["collidesWith"].includes(filterA["group"]) || filterB["group"] == 0) 
        && (filterA["collidesWith"].includes(filterB["group"]) || filterA["group"] == 0);
}
```

The above is giving the error: `filterB["collidesWith"]` is undefined.
After further inspection I used a `console.log()` statement to find out what was happening to this object (`filterB`), and it returned this:

```
{category: 1, mask: 4294967295, group: 3, collidesWith: Array(1)}
category: 1
collidesWith: [0]
group: 3
mask: 4294967295
__proto__: Object}

{category: 1, mask: 4294967295, group: 1}
category: 1
group: 1
mask: 4294967295
__proto__: Object}
```

The second object appears to be a continuation of the `console.log()` function (as it continues to log after printing)

**EDIT:**
I found that `filterA` is doing the opposite,
First it prints:

```
{category: 1, mask: 4294967295, group: 1}
category: 1
group: 1
mask: 4294967295
__proto__: Object}

{category: 1, mask: 4294967295, group: 2, collidesWith: Array(1)}
category: 1
collidesWith: [0]
group: 2
mask: 4294967295
__proto__: Object}
```

Note: When I initialise the colliding bodies the collision filter options are the same the values that appear (`filterA`) and disappear (`filterB`) respectively

Is there some bug elsewhere in my code? or is this some other Matter.js feature that I've overlooked?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show a [mcve], preferably a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do), that I can run to see the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I think that there was some small bug, as there is a lot of code to go through to get an example by which it could be debugged, I have posted an answer to show I fixed it. Sorry if this post became unrelated, in any way.

Comment: That's OK--I appreciate the [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not updating this thread earlier,
Though I have not found the bug,
I realised that this wasn't the best way to this for my particular simulation and instead created a much better system without needing to check these undefined variables.
I instead created a collision filter called, layer and assigned every single agent to a different layer, the things that can collide with everything on `layer: 0`, the things that collide with nothing at `layer: -1`, and used the following code to achieve this. I gave this `collisionFilter.layer` property to every object in my simulation.

```
Detector.canCollide = function (filterA, filterB) {
    if (filterA.layer != -1 && filterB.layer != -1){
        return (filterA.layer == filterB.layer || (filterA.layer == 0 || filterB.layer==0));
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```